# Why Ficus benjamina Leaves are Curled/Half Closed

Tags: leaves, ficus

few months ago i took cuttings from Ficus mother plant and put them in water after 1 month new root came out and then i  put the cuttings in the pot with peat moss and perlite mixture. After another month i put the plant outside , But for some reason leaves are semi-closed . It is getting i think 6 hours of direct sunlight. Plant looks healthy.

I live in Saudi Arabia. Just like summer is hot, winter is also very very chilly. Could this be the reason that leaves are semi-closed

[image] 
[image]
[image]

You will notice that some leaves are damaged that happened when i moved plant outside in direct sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

Leaves curl to conserve moisture.  By adding shade to it's own leaf it can slow down transpiration.  Make sure the plant is getting enough water.  It should always be moist, never allowed to dry out.  &/OR Give the plant more shade during the hot times of the day.  Provider it with morning sun, then give it bright indirect light the remainder of the day.

Comment: Update: Plant died due to extreme heat in August. It was in window and was getting just 1-2 hours of direct sunlight but i guess it was enough to kill this plant and then hot air came and did the rest of job. Now i have only one benjamina which i placed inside and gets indirect sunlight. Im working on it to give a bonsai shape.